# Regular Expression for Valid Year Range

Tags: python, regex, validation, datetime, plotly-dash

#### Purpose:

Hi there, I'm trying to create a regular expression for the `dash_core_components.Input` "pattern" input property to validate year range inputs.

I have the below Python v3.6.3 code that provides regexp for validation of input formats (valid per me...):

```
import datetime as dt

full_year_   = dt.datetime.now().year
mill_        = str(full_year_)[0]
century_     = str(full_year_)[1]
decade_      = str(int(str(full_year_)[2]))
prev_decade_ = str(int(str(full_year_)[2]) - 1)
year_        = str(full_year_)[3]

prior_decades  = f'{mill_}{century_}[0-{prev_decade_}][0-9]'
current_decade = f'{mill_}{century_}{decade_}[0-{year_}]'


def century():
    return f'^({prior_decades})|({current_decade})$'


def century_set():
    # Acceptable Examples: 2018, 2019, 2020 | 2018:2020
    return f'^\s*({prior_decades}|{current_decade})([,\s]+{prior_decades}|[,\s]+{current_decade}|[,\s]*)*$|'\
           f'^\s*({prior_decades}|{current_decade})(\s*:\s*{prior_decades}|\s*:\s*{current_decade}|\s*)?$'
```

#### Problem Statement:

What I'd like to implement in `century_set()`, if possible, is the ability to use a regular expression to verify if a range is valid or not.

In other words:

```
"2018:2020" >> Valid
"2020:2018" >> Invalid
```

#### Or...

Is there a round-about way to apply additional criteria to validate  an input for `dash_core_components.Input`?

Comment: Maybe convert the year into int and work on it like `if year in range(2018, 2020+1): #do something`. Catching years in regex seems a bit unnatural.

Comment: @Evgeny, the pattern input property must remain a regexp. So I don't believe an if/else statement could handle this... I may be mistaken though...

Comment: Imho, you have two steps to make - validate input is a year (four-digit int), and second check if the year (int) falls into range you want. You may also note years are often drop-down menus, for reasons to save parsing the input, where you can.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple workaround could be to have `century_set()` in the callback.

So something like:

```
@app.callback(Output('e_msg', 'value'),
              [Input('year_input_box', 'value')]
def validate_yr(year_input):
    error_msg = century_set(year_input) # Modify century_set to take a year as input and after validating, return an error message if not satisfying the regex criteria
    return error_msg
```

Then use `error_msg` as a text area next to input box to display if is not as per regex.

Further tweak your return to go ahead with rest of the program if regex passes the input correctly.